# Natural Deduction Proof $\neg(P \to Q) \vdash Q \to P$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I am trying to answer Question 3(e) in Exercise 1.2 of Huth and Ryan's Logic in Computer Science book for revision and I am stuck on it. The question asks you to prove the validity of the following sequent:

$\neg(P \to Q) \vdash  Q \to P$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove it informally?

Comment: I can understand why it makes sense informally, but I have no idea how to actually write that out formally

Comment: OK. Here's an idea. You start by assuming the LHS holds, then start a subproof with $Q$ as a premise. From here my hint is this: prove $P\to Q$ within this subproof.

Comment: I understand that by proving P→Q I can then derive a falsity but with just Q as an assumption and the premise as ¬(P → Q) I have no idea how to get P→Q within the assumption of Q

Comment: Sure you do. What's the most natural way of proving a conditional statement (most of the time)? Start a new subproof with $P$ as a premise. What should be your goal within this subproof?

Comment: Oh I think I know what you mean, so would the proof look like this?

Line 1: ¬(P → Q)                 premise
Line 2: Q                             assumption
Line 3:     P                          assumption
Line 4:     Q                         (from line 2)
Line 5: P → Q                      → introduction, 3-4
Line 6: ⊥                              ¬ elimination, 1,5
Line 7: P                              ⊥ elimination, 6
Line 8: Q → P                      → introduction, 2-7

Comment: That's fine. Now maybe change your name to atleastmediocre and find alternative proofs. It's unlikely that the informal proof you had in mind looks like this. Try to formalize the informal proof you thought of.

Comment: @GitGud, I'm very curious as to what other proof you were thinking of. The one just provided is the one I came up with as well.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Informally, much more natural to me would be something along the lines of $$\neg(P\to Q)\implies P\land \neg Q\implies \neg Q\lor P\implies Q\to P.$$

Comment: @GitGud, if I try to render that proof in natural deduction it becomes way, way longer. In fact, just the first step involves proving $\neg Q$, that is, deriving $\bot$ from $Q$, which is already almost all of the proof that lessthanmediocre presented. Edit: and in fact, why bother proving *both* $P$ and $\neg Q$ at all, if you're moving to a disjunction in the second step?

Comment: It doesn't surprise me at all that the proof suggested by what I said is much longer, that is often the case with more natural proofs. What I presented was an informal argument based on what's natural to me. One way I think of $\neg (P\to Q)$ is as $P\land \neg Q$, only after this can I derive $\neg Q$. Of course formally it doesn't work this way.

Comment: @GitGud My informal proof would be more like $\lnot$(p $\rightarrow$ q).  So, p.  Consequently, (q $\rightarrow$ p) (we could have also inferred (r $\rightarrow$ p)).  I don't have the book, but from what I can tell that informal proof has quite a few more steps in that natural deduction system.  I'd probably end up using the law of the excluded middle, even though $\lnot$(p $\rightarrow$ q) $\vdash$ (r $\rightarrow$ p) holds for Wajsberg-Lukasiewicz three-valued logic.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Your alternative totally escaped me. Now it's natural to me too.

Answer (score 3):

1) $\lnot (P \to Q)$ --- premise

2) $Q$ --- assumed [a]

3) $P \to Q$ --- from 2) by $\to$-intro

4) $\bot$ --- contradiction from 1) and 3)

5) $P$ --- from 4) by [$\bot$-eim](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4)

> 6) $Q \to P$ --- from 2) and 5) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

Answer (score 2):

Following the nomenclature as demonstrated in [the solutions of your book](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/course/DAT060/huthryan_lics2_sol.pdf) (this particular question is not included, so this is not plagiarism):

```
1. ¬(P→Q)  assumption
  2. Q     assumption
    3. P   assumption
    4. Q   copy 2
  5. P→Q   →i 3-4
  6. ⊥     ¬e 5 1
  7. P     ⊥e 6
8. Q→P     →i 2-7
```

Where it used boxes, I used indentation. I won't draw boxes. I simply refuse to do so.